# Filtering data frame in R based on multiple conditions and interdependent variables

Tags: r, filter

I have three variables that are interdepedent. I want to exclude all oberservations in which a participant has indicated "nein" (no) in the variable "fruehere_FAS_Nutzung" (used a FAS before) and also indicated "ausgewaehlt" (selected) in the variable "frueheres_FAS_ODEG" (FAS at company A) or "ausgewählt" in the variable "frueheres_FAS_andere" (FAS at other company), like for example particpant 13 did.

```
1                    ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
2                    ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
3                    ja        ausgewaehlt          ausgewaehlt
4                    ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
5                    ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
6            weiß nicht               <NA>                 <NA>
7                    ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
8                    ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
9                    ja  nicht ausgewaehlt          ausgewaehlt
10                   ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
11                   ja        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt
12                   ja  nicht ausgewaehlt          ausgewaehlt
**13                 nein        ausgewaehlt    nicht ausgewaehlt**
```

I used:

```
fasan_scores_filtered_FAS_Nutzung <- fasan_scores %<% 
   filter(!(fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_ODEG == 'ausgewaehlt')) | 
   filter(!(fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_andere == 'ausgewaehlt'))
```

When I do that, I get every "fruehere_FAS_Nutzung = nein" excluded from the data frame even and only the "fruehere_FAS_Nutzung = ja" remeain, regardless of the other conditions. But I only want to exclude the "nein" if they meet one of the attached conditions above

Comment: Can you please include a reproducible example (with data) and format your question using code blocks? It's not clear if your bullet points are two different options you've tried or if they're part of the same line of code. If you're doing a filter with an `|` - it should be inside a single `filter()` call, not two.

Comment: The sample data you provided only has 1 `'nein'`, so I do not think it demonstrates the problem. Please choose sample data that makes the problem clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following sample data:

```
df = expand.grid(
    fruehere_FAS_Nutzung = c("ja", "nein", "weiss nicht"),
    frueheres_FAS_ODEG = c("ausgewaehlt", "nicht ausgewaehlt", NA),
    frueheres_FAS_andere = c("ausgewaehlt", "nicht ausgewaehlt", NA),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can filter out the unwanted rows like this:

```
df[!(df$fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == "nein" &
     (!is.na(df$frueheres_FAS_ODEG) & df$frueheres_FAS_ODEG == "ausgewaehlt" |
      !is.na(df$frueheres_FAS_andere) & df$frueheres_FAS_andere == "ausgewaehlt")),]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you are having trouble with your and/or logic or how to properly write it out using the `filter` function. Based on the sample data from @BigFinger, here are a few `dplyr` options.

1. This is what I *think* you were trying to express in your text description at the start, but I could be wrong.

```
df %>%
  filter(!(fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' &
           (frueheres_FAS_ODEG == 'ausgewaehlt' | frueheres_FAS_andere == 'ausgewaehlt')))
```

2. If you were happy with the logic in your code, but couldn't format it properly, these all perform the same filter.

```
df %>%
  filter(!(fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_ODEG == 'ausgewaehlt')) %>%
  filter(!(fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_andere == 'ausgewaehlt'))

df %>%
  filter(!(fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_ODEG == 'ausgewaehlt'),
         !(fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_andere == 'ausgewaehlt'))

df %>%
  filter(!((fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_ODEG == 'ausgewaehlt') |
           (fruehere_FAS_Nutzung == 'nein' & frueheres_FAS_andere == 'ausgewaehlt')))
```